# Things that go "hand-in-hand" to make me resign

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, formality, infinitives

Looking for a formal sentence to explain the reasons for leaving my previous job, and for some reasons i insist on using the phrase "hand-in-hand" in the sentence. Is it formal and grammatically correct to say:

*"Interpersonal conflicts, discrimination, gossips, harassment and bullying, all went hand-in-hand to make me quit/resign"*

Appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything "wrong" with it per se. It might help if you edit your post to include why you think it is informal and other words or phrases you decided not to use.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to make sure that the phrase "hand-in-hand" could be followed by the "to-infinitive"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly grammatical to say *went hand-in-hand*.

But if you're looking for something more formal in that sentence, I would suggest replacing it with **combined**.

(Regardless of what wording you choose, I would remove the comma that follows *bullying*.)

Comment: Should I replace the comma with dot?

Comment: No, I wouldn't suggest any punctuation after it. Unless what you'd actually meant to write is something like *interpersonal conflicts, such as discrimination, gossiping, harassment, and bullying,  . . .* In which case, note how I rephrased it. I had initially been reading it as *interpersonal conflicts* being one of the several items you were listing.

Answer (score 0):

A more formal phrase might be "worked in concert"

"Interpersonal conflicts, discrimination, gossips, harassment and bullying, all worked in concert to make me quit/resign"